# Prove that $\lim_{n\to \infty} [\int_E f^n (x) dx)]^{1/n} = M$ where $M = \sup_{x\in E} f (x)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration

In the book of *Mathematical Analysis II*, by Zorich at page 128, it is given that

> Let $E$ be a Jordan-measurable set of nonzero measure, $f : E →
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ a continuous nonnegative integrable function on $E$, and
>   $M = \sup_{x\in E} f (x)$. Prove that
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} [\int_E f^n (x) dx)]^{1/n} = M$$

I have already proved that 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} [\int_E f^n (x) dx)]^{1/n} \leq M$$
since $E$ is Jordan measurable and has nonzero measure, but I'm having trouble proving the reverse of that statement, so any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

I'm new to this topic, and I even do not understand the premise of the asked question, so I would appreciate if you could post an answer that is formulated in terms of the statement that I have given in the question.

Comment: This question has been asked before.

Comment: @mickep I would appreciate if you could provide the link of the considered question.

Comment: Are we supposed to know the book just from that title????

Comment: @mathworker21 Sorry, I forgot to add the author, thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\epsilon > 0$. Let $F = \{x : f(x) > M-\epsilon\}$. Then,

$[\int_E f^n(x)dx]^{1/n} \ge [\int_F f^n(x)dx]^{1/n} \ge [(M-\epsilon)^n \mu(F)]^{1/n} = (M-\epsilon) \mu(F)^{1/n}$.

Since $f$ is continuous, $\mu(F) > 0$. Since $f$ is integrable, $\mu(F) < \infty$. So, if we let $n \to \infty$, we see that we can get a lower bound of $M-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have some questions. First of all, How does the fact that $f$ is continuous implies $\mu(F) > 0$ ?

Comment: Secondly, how does $f$ is integrable imply that $\mu(F) < \infty.$ ?

Comment: I was hoping you would fill in those details. For continuity, if you are greater than $M-\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ at some point, you are greater than $M-\epsilon$ in a neighborhood around that point. For integrability, if you are greater than $M-\epsilon$ on a set with infinite measure.... that's bad

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new to this topic, so I would appreciate if you could be more specific.

Comment: More specific about what? If you are doing measure theory, you should already be comfortable with continuity. For the integrability argument, note $\infty > \int_F f^(x)dx \ge (M-\epsilon)^n \mu(F)$, so of course $\mu(F)$ can't be infinite. (Think intuitively - if you have a function which is bounded away from 0 for a set with infinite measure, then the integral will be infinite)

Comment: I'm not doing measure theory, please see the book that I'm using.

Comment: By the way, how do we know that $f$ is integrable on $F$, I mean we need to know that the boundary of $F$ is Jordan measure zero because $\int_F f dx = \int_{F \subset I} f\chi_F dx$, and $f\chi_F$ is discontinuous on $\partial F$.